# OpenID Oauth API Authentication

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, open-id-connect

I have a connected an Application that is setup with the Oauth using an Open ID authentication provider server.  The use case is a user logs into my website that uses the same authentication open ID server.  This works.  Now I have a page for them to enter information into and I want to login them into salesforce and submit this data via salesforce RestAPI.  I cannot find any samples on how this should be setup or how the header for the API should work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for this. This has illustrated all the list of steps that would allow you get connected to OpenID oauth2 salesforce auth.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&language=th

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want capture form data from a logged in user of your website into Salesforce.  Am I right, if yes, then you can do web to lead kind of an integration.

But however if the use case is that they need to be redirected from your website to Salesforce (with OpenId authentication) seamlessly to fill in a form then:

1. You can configure your OpenId server at Setup -> Auth. Providers -> Click on "New" button and configure your auth provider
2. Place a link in your webpage to redirect your user to that page in salesforce

If these are not 2 uses cases your are talking about, then please let me know more, so that I should be able to give you some solution.